# Django Unhandled Exception Troubleshoot

Tags: django

Django has been set up on Site5 and was running smoothly, till I tried to install django-lockdown and then something broke. I'm unable to get back to my last working state, unfortunately.

Here's the error log:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/projectname/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/projectname/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 129, in <module>
mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/projectname/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 20, in <module>
mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/projectname/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 3, in <module>
mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/projectname/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 3, in <module>
mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/projectname/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/projectname/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path
mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/projectname/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/projectname/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
```

I have been trying to decipher the cause of the problem from the error log, but have totally no clue at the moment. If anyone should find these error log lines familiar, do enlighten me on how I can fixed this problem...

Comment: Try setting `DEBUG=True` in your settings file, if not done already.

Comment: Yes, Django in development mode, DEBUG = True and TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG sorry left that out.

Comment: Can you get back last working state by removing django-lockdown?

Comment: I thought I could as I had done that before, but upon removing the 4 lockdown lines from settings.py, it still returned Unhandled Exception. In that time, a support specialist over at Site5 had helped me to install a true local copy of python, instead of a symlink to the server's copy. Could that have messed things up?

Comment: And why on earth did I get a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the ownership of the new python/django install? The fastCGI module might not have access rights.

Answer (score 0):

Another version of Django was messing things up, causing that error. I ended up fixing it by resetting the hosting account (and thus, files). Working clean slate better than a spoilt web app!